# Chessboard and Catalan numbers

Tags: problem-solving, catalan-numbers

Let's consider labelling the square of a $2\times n$ chessboard from $1$ to $2n$ such that the numbers increase from left-to-right and bottom-to-top.

Prove that the number of such labellings equals the $n$-th Catalan number $C_n$

I still have no clue how to even start this problem after all the "research" I've done.  Extremely confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can make a bijection onto the set of strings of $n$ pairs of regular parenthesis, as follows:

Let "$($" stand on exactly the indices in the upper row, and "$)$" on the indices in the lower row.

For example, $\pmatrix{1&2&4\\3&5&6}$ corresponds to "$(()())$", and
$\pmatrix{1&3&5\\2&4&6}$ to "$()()()$".